# We say "we got on the large ship" but "we got in the small boat". Do we say "we leapt off the large ship" and "we leapt out of the small boat"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Because a large ship has a large platform, so we say "**we got on the large ship**".

And, because a small boat has a very small platform, so we say "**we got in the small boat**".

Now, you want to remove yourself from the ship or boat by jumping very high.

Do we say "**we leapt off the large ship**" and "**we leapt out of the small boat**"?

Comment: The 'platform' of a ship is called the deck. This word is used for both the top one that is open to the air, and the different levels below.

Answer (score 1):

You only get 'in' a boat if it is the 'hollowed-out' type like a dingy, rowing boat or the lifeboats from the Titanic.  You sit in it and are enclosed by the sides.  Boats with decks, like yachts, you would be 'on'

Do we say "we leapt off the large ship" and "we leapt out of the small boat"?...........Yes, if the boat is as have I indicated.